# textFiled shouldChangeCharactersInRange function didn't work

Tags: textfield, cclayer

I'm using cocos2d CClayer.

I made Submit TextField Class to use submit name.

I followed some blogger and managed to show textFiled, but the shouldChangeCharactersInRange didn't call at all.

How do i call shouldChangeCharactersInRange? (I didn't use xib)

waiting for your help.

code bellow.
(in Submit.h)

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *mTextField;
@property (readonly) NSString *enteredText;
```

(in Submit.m)

```
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle okButtonTitle:(NSString *)okButtonTitle{
    if(self = [super initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)okButtonTitle, nil]) {
        UITextField *theTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 65.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
        [theTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self addSubview:theTextField];
        self.mTextField = theTextField;
        [theTextField release];

    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)textField: (UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > MAXLENGTH) ? NO : YES;
}
```

(in GameLayer.h)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Submit *submitForm;
```

(in GameLayer.m)

```
-(void) submit:(id) sender {
    Submit *prompt = [Submit alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Post Score" message:@"Enter Your Name\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Okay"];
    CGAffineTransform moveDown = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-10);
    [prompt setTransform:moveDown];
    self.submitForm = prompt;
    [submitForm show];
    [prompt release];   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to call the UITextField Delegate method

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:  (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

,

you have to set delegate property of uitextfield.

As,

```
theTextField.delegate = self;
```